# monitoring and blocking network traffic

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

Which is the best program for monitoring and blocking network traffic through Local network from computer, which is connected to that network?

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: Now a duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/116426/monitoring-and-blocking-network-traffic

Comment: What OS on the computer?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use http://superuser.com/questions/17219/block-all-network-traffic-from-to-laptop-except-explicit-apps-protocols-targets